# Oracle10g database DMBS_CRYPTO error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database

I have the following source code modified from [this](http://datatothemax.com/blog/blog.php?entry_id=1328094544) example to use `NUMBERS` instead of `VARCHAR2`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE gen_encr
AS
    FUNCTION encrypt (p_PlainText NUMBER) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
    FUNCTION decrypt (p_Encrypted RAW) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC;
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY gen_encr
AS
EncryptionType PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                           + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                           + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

EncryptionKey RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('ThisTextIsMyEncryptionKeyForThisPackage');

FUNCTION encrypt (p_PlainText NUMBER) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
    IS
        encrypted_raw      RAW (1024);
    BEGIN
        encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        (  src => UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER (p_PlainText),
           typ => EncryptionType,
           key => EncryptionKey
        );
   RETURN encrypted_raw;
END encrypt;

FUNCTION decrypt (p_Encrypted RAW) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
    IS
        decrypt_raw      RAW (1024);
    BEGIN
        decrypt_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
        (   src => p_Encrypted,
            typ => EncryptionType,
            key => EncryptionKey
        );
    RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER (decrypt_raw));
END decrypt;
END;
/
```

However, when i ran the statement `SELECT sys.gen_encr.encrypt(sal) FROM emp`, I get the following error.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at "SYS.GEN_ENCR", line 13
```

Some google searching suggested the error might be that the RAW datatype can only accept 2000bytes.

However, in this case I don't see why there is an error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should not use the SYS schema to build your own objects.  SYS and SYSTEM are special accounts which Oracle uses to manege the database.  By using those schemas as part of your application you are running the risk of corrupting your database.

Answer (score 2):

This is dead simple: your key is too long.  It is 37 characters which you're attempting to stuff into a `RAW(32)` variable.  Shorten it to 32 characters and that error will disappear.